# How to use Kotlin's readln() in an IntelliJ IDEA scratch tab

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to read input from the user (me) when troubleshooting code in a scratch tab in IntelliJ IDEA? If I try to run this simple statement:

```
val something = readln()
println(something)
```

...and then run the scratch (Ctrl Shift R), it hangs for a while and returns this in the Scratch Output tab at the bottom:

```
Couldn't get scratch execution result - stopped by timeout (30,000 ms)
```

I can't see any place where I can input something. The right-hand side is read-only.

Comment: There is no way to do it right now. I created a feature request — https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-23275.

Answer (score 1):

Run it here:

[image]

This will bring output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works, but that runs it in a normal "run configuration", not in the scratch window.